# Choose the best classifier to predict the label of strings of a regular language

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, machine-learning, classification

I have to tackle this problem:
I have some strings that are my training set. These strings belong to a regular language corresponding to a deterministic finite automata (hidden namely I don't now it, neither the language nor the automata). A string is labeled like positive if belong to hidden language and negative otherwise. The strings of training set are correctly labeled.
I have to build a statistical classifier from training set that predicts the label of strings not seen (generalization) in the best way (better accuracy, respect to actual labeling of hidden language/automa).
I have to choose between Support Vector Machine (SVM), Recurrent Neural Network and Convolutional Neural Network.

What could be the best choice and why?

Comment: If you hadn't restricted the set of methods that can be used, I would have answered "any of the offline methods for automaton learning that libalf has implemented": http://libalf.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/index.php?page=about - These are specialized to your application case.

Comment: @DCTLib I'm experimenting active learning. In a real context I have not a Oracle that can answer equivalences query and then I must approximate the Oracle with a classifier. My goal isn't simply find the minimal dfa from strings in training set (but build a classifier that I can use like a Oracle).

Answer (score 2):

My bet would go to a Recurrent Neural Network, as it closely models some (fuzzy, non-discrete) state machine as each character is output. A decent start to read up on RNNs for this purpose is to read the article [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) which describes character-level RNNs used to predict text.